# uso do Sys.sleep

Tags: r, plot

Não consigo fazer um gráfico ponto a ponto, o R `plot` o gráfico depois fica na contagem do `Sys.sleep`, alguém me ajuda?

```
  n=1
  Cn=6.45
  x<-3
  t<- seq(1,20)
  for (i in 1:21) {
  flux  = round(Cn*sin(n*pi*x / 5)*exp(-(pi^2*n^2/25)*t), digits = 2)
  flux
  plot(flux, type = "o", col = "red4")
  Sys.sleep(.25)
  }
```

Como posso aumentar o tamanho do gráfico?

Answer (score 1):

Gráfico ponto a ponto seria um gráfico tipo uma animação? Se for, o código abaixo resolve o teu problema:

```
# criacao as variaveis e calculo do flux

n  <- 1
Cn <- 6.45
x  <- 3
t  <- seq(1, 20)
flux  <- round(Cn*sin(n*pi*x / 5)*exp(-(pi^2*n^2/25)*t), digits=2)

# cria um grafico vazio com as dimensoes
plot(flux ~ t, type="n") 

for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  points(flux[i] ~ t[i], type="o", col="red4")
  Sys.sleep(.25)
}
```

O problema do código original estava em utilizar o comando `plot(flux, type = "o", col = "red4")`. Ele era rodado 21 vezes, sempre criando um gráfico completo com todos os 20 pontos. Ao utilizar o comando `points`, eu consigo adicionar os pontos do gráfico um a um, sem apagar os anteriores.